# Can I use the Select DISTINCT function in Excel using an ODBC connection to keep from importing duplicate column entries?

Tags: sql, excel, oracle, duplicates, distinct

I am trying to import some table data into an Excel 2016 worksheet from an Oracle db using an ODBC connection. However, I do not want duplicate row entries in a specific column. When I try to use the Select DISTINCT function, I am getting an error message.

Here is the column I am trying to NOT import duplicate entries from.

```
EQP_CODE

C0Z9960SM

C0Z9960SM

C0Z9960SM

C0ZZX20SA

C0ZZX20SA

C0ZZX20SB

C0ZZX20SC
```

Here is the code throwing the error. If I replace `DISTINCT EQP_CODE with the * symbol then the code works. But I get the duplicate entries that I do not want.

```
Odbc.Query("dsn=METS Oracle ODBC UA Connection", "SELECT DISTINCT EQP_CODE
FROM TEQP#(lf)WHERE(TEQP.EQP_TYPE Like 'CT' and TEQP.SITE >0 and TEQP.EQP_USER2 <>' ' and TEQP.EQP_CODE <>' ') 
ORDER BY TEQP.EQP_TYPE")
```

My expected results should be..

```
EQP_CODE

C0Z9960SM

C0ZZX20SA

C0ZZX20SB

C0ZZX20SC
```

Comment: What *is* the exact error you get -- and are you sure you didn't just make a typo with `EQP_CO` when you meant `EQP_CODE`?

Comment: I did make a typo in my post. Not sure how that happened. When I read it before actually posting it looked correct. Anyway, the table column name is EQP_CODE, not EQP_C or EQP_CO.

Comment: The exact error message is: DataSource.Error: ODBC: ERROR [HY000] [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-0701:not a Selected expression OdbcErrors=Table